# trimming a column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel column with data like

{"delivery_week":"Week 5"}

{"delivery_week":"Week 3"}

{"delivery_week":"Week 7"}

How can I create a formular that removes everything in this column but the weeks, so it looks like this:

Week 5

Week 3

Week 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using anyone of the following formulas:

[image]

---

```
=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1:A3,":"""),"""")
```

---

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTAFTER(A1:A3,":"""),"""",)
```

---

```
=TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"""",,1),,-1)
```

---

Answer (score 1):

`=INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(a,""""),,4)`

or

`=MAP(A1:A3,LAMBDA(a,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(a,""""),,4)))`

`=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(A1:A3,":"""),"""")`